# Execute multiple commands for some condition

Tags: bash

I get that the second command is executed even when `i != 1`.

```
(( i == 1)) && florg="${fl%-*.png}.org" ; touch "$florg"
```

But want the two commands to execute just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is use a regular `if` statement:

```bsh
if ((i == 1)); then
  florg="${fl%-*.png}.org"
  touch "$florg"
fi
```

Otherwise use braces to group the commands:

```bsh
(( i == 1)) && { florg="${fl%-*.png}.org" ; touch "$florg"; }
```

See [3.2.5.3 Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) in the manual.

If you don't need to keep the variable, parentheses can be used (which executes the commands in a subshell). Parentheses are more forgiving about whitespace and semicolons:

```bsh
((i == 1)) && (florg="${fl%-*.png}.org"; touch "$florg")
```

Comment: Looks like the last `;` is really important.

Comment: Yes. It's documented. Read the provided link.

Comment: Not many people know that.  You are right.